# $\int \frac{x^4-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{x^4-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}\,dx$$

My attempt,

I changed it to $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}} \, dx-\int \frac 1 {x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}} \, dx$, but I stuck here.

Any method to solve this integral? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to @achille-hui 's excellent answer, one could also proceed by setting $u=x/\sqrt{1+x^2+x^4}$ (these Euler-type change of variables are often successful).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everytime I see an integrand that look sort of "symmetric" under $x \to x^{-1}$,
I will try to see whether it can be reexpressed in terms of $x \pm x^{-1}$.

One useful identity to remember is 
$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{d(x+x^{-1})}{x - x^{-1}} = \frac{d(x-x^{-1})}{x + x^{-1}}$$

This trick does work for the integral at hand.

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^4-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}} dx &= \int \frac{x^2-x^{-2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}+1}} \frac{dx}{x} \\
&= \int \frac{x^2-x^{-2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}+1}} \frac{d(x-x^{-1})}{x+x^{-1}} \\
&= \int \frac{(x-x^{-1}) \, d(x - x^{-1})}{\sqrt{(x-x^{-1})^2+3}} \\
&= \int d\sqrt{(x-x^{-1})^2+3} \\
&= \sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}+1} + \text{const.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you explain how the dx/x works ?

Comment: @Mathxx $\frac{d(x-x^{-1})}{x+x^{-1}} = \frac{\color{red}{(1 + x^{-2})}dx}{\color{blue}{x+x^{-1}}} = \frac{\color{red}{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}}{\color{blue}{\frac{x^2+1}{x}}} dx = \frac{dx}{x}$.

Answer (score 6):

For $x>0,$

$$I=\int \frac{x^4-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}\,dx=\int\dfrac{x^3\left(2x-\dfrac2{x^3}\right)\ dx}{2x^3\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}+1}}$$

Set $x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}+1=y$